# modify android-formatting.xml in android adt for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, formatting, adt

I want to edit the reformating which comes with the official Android ADT in eclipse, is this possible? 
I want, for example, remove the break after a long class decleration.

I have the official AOSP source on my computer and found a the android-formatting.xml, is it the same as in the Android ADT? If yes, How can I override the ADT formatting and can use my custom file which I can import (a modified android-formatting.xml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want, for example, remove the break after a long class decleration.

I am not aware that Android specifies any formatting for Java classes. That is handled by Eclipse and can be modified from within Eclipse itself (Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter).

Comment: Ok, I thought that because ADT have a custom XML formatting, so Java formatting is the same. 
I imported the android-formatting.xml and I use this from now on, do you know how to change the break behaviour?

Comment: @Leandros: Since I have no idea what you consider a "break after a long class decleration", I suggest that you visit Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter, create a new format, and experiment.